# Is there any tool to visualize actors' relations in Akka.net?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, akka.net

Is there any way/tool to visualize actors' relations in Akka.net?

I found myself only Petabridge's tool but it show only actors paths without connections between them.

Need somth like this:
https://github.com/ouven/akka-visualmailbox

Comment: Have you encountered with the [Akka.Visualizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.Visualizer)? Unfortunately it is in alpha state since 2016.

Comment: @PeterCsala i cant even guess how to use it)

Comment: I have found [this how to setup guide](https://devhub.io/repos/corneliutusnea-Akka.Visualizer)

Comment: I've actually been working on a [port](https://github.com/to11mtm/Akka.Metrics.MetricMailbox) of Ouven's visualizer. Still troubleshooting why counts don't display in the sample, but Basic Visualization, Arrow Weights and Path display on hover-over are all present.